# SQL Unions with counts and dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Asking again, but hopefully clearer. I have the following situation which is working perfectly You can see [Sql Unions Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279017/sql-union-with-counts) for the original question which was answered!

```
DECLARE @imvw_woap_code_with_cust TABLE (
        pkey INT,
        Code_id VARCHAR(200),
        code_type_id VARCHAR(200),
        asset_standard_id VARCHAR(200),
        date_completed DATETIME
    )
INSERT INTO @imvw_woap_code_with_cust(pkey,Code_id,code_type_id,asset_standard_id,date_completed)
    SELECT 101480,'Alarmining','A-Problem','1 East','2017-08-10 02:00:30.013'
    UNION SELECT 103350,'Fluid/Gas Leak (Out)','A-Problem','2 west','2017-08-10 02:00:30.013'
    UNION SELECT 104033,'plug/Pwr Cord Damg','A-Problem','2 west','2017-08-10 02:00:30.013'
    UNION SELECT 107296,'Alarmining','A-Problem','2 west','2017-09-11 02:00:30.013'
    UNION SELECT 106404,'Incoming Inspect','A-Problem','2 west','2017-08-10 02:00:30.013'
    UNION SELECT 106407,'Incoming Inspect','A-Problem','2 west','2017-09-11 02:00:30.013'
    UNION SELECT 106408,'Incoming Inspect','A-Problem','2 west','2017-09-12 02:00:30.013'

DECLARE @IMTBL_CODE TABLE (
    pkey INT,
    Code_id VARCHAR(200),
    code_type_id VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO @IMTBL_CODE(pkey,Code_id,code_type_id)
    SELECT 100064,'1-NO PROBLEM CODE ENTERED','A-Problem'
    UNION SELECT 100068,'Alarmining','A-Problem'
    UNION SELECT 100069,'Battery Failure','A-Problem'
    UNION SELECT 100070,'Incoming Inspect','A-Problem'
    UNION SELECT 100071,'Fluid/Gas Leak (Out)','A-Problem'
    UNION SELECT 100072,'Case Damaged','A-Problem'
    UNION SELECT 100073,'plug/Pwr Cord Damg','A-Problem'


CREATE VIEW cause_codes as
SELECT
        possibilities.code_id AS code_id,
        possibilities.asset_standard_id,
        Count(U.pkey) AS [COUNT]
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.asset_standard_id,b.code_id
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT asset_standard_id FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT code_id FROM @imtbl_code
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT CODE_ID AS [ID] FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust 
    ) AS b
) AS possibilities
LEFT OUTER JOIN @imvw_woap_code_with_cust AS U ON U.code_id = possibilities.code_id
    AND possibilities.asset_standard_id=u.asset_standard_id
    and u.code_type_id='A-Problem'
GROUP BY possibilities.code_id, possibilities.asset_standard_id
order by [count]
```

Once I created this into a view (cause_codes) it returns a neat table that has the count of how many times a code appears (including 0 counts as well).

```
CODE ID                   asset_standard_id     count
1-NO PROBLEM CODE ENTERED   1 East                0
1-NO PROBLEM CODE ENTERED   2 west                0
Battery Failure             1 East                0
Battery Failure             2 west                0
Case Damaged                1 East                0
Case Damaged                2 west                0
Fluid/Gas Leak (Out)        1 East                0
Incoming Inspect            1 East                0
plug/Pwr Cord Damg          1 East                0
plug/Pwr Cord Damg          2 west                1
Fluid/Gas Leak (Out)        2 west                1
Alarmining                  1 East                1
Alarmining                  2 west                1
Incoming Inspect            2 west                3
```

Then client has come back and wanted dates added
So if I added dates to the view

```
ALTER VIEW cause_codes as
    SELECT
            possibilities.code_id AS code_id,
            possibilities.asset_standard_id,
            Count(U.pkey) AS [COUNT],
            U.date_created
    FROM (
        SELECT
            a.asset_standard_id,b.code_id
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT asset_standard_id FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT code_id FROM @imtbl_code
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT CODE_ID AS [ID] FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust 
        ) AS b
    ) AS possibilities
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @imvw_woap_code_with_cust AS U ON U.code_id = possibilities.code_id
        AND possibilities.asset_standard_id=u.asset_standard_id
        and u.code_type_id='A-Problem'
    GROUP BY possibilities.code_id, possibilities.asset_standard_id,date_created
    order by [count]
```

and then do a search

```
 select * from cause_codes where asset_standard_id = '2 west' and date_completed > '2017-09-10 02:00:30.013' and date_completed < '2017-09-12 02:00:30.013'
```

The table splits rows like this ->

```
Incoming Inspect       2 west                1   2017-09-11 02:00:30.013' 
Incoming Inspect       2 west                1   2017-09-12 02:00:30.013'
```

Is there a way that I can do this(add a date to search by), but still keep the single row with a correct count?

I hope this is clear... its quite an issue.
Thanks for taking the time to read my book :)

Comment: Would it be ok to take a MIN or MAX date from the result? If so then you could add the date_created into your grouping to normalize your counts, or do you want the total for all dates within the group to return within any arbitrary window?

Comment: It would need to return within any arbirtary window which.. well sucks! LOL

Comment: I think your data should be --> Incoming Inspect(3) | Alarmining(1) for the filter you provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there my way first, I haven't measure performance.

```
;WITH Activity As
(
    SELECT Count = COUNT(*),Customer.Code_id,Customer.asset_standard_id
    FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust Customer
    GROUP BY Customer.Code_id,asset_standard_id
),
Groups AS
(
    SELECT Code_id,asset_standard_id 
    FROM @IMTBL_CODE Codes
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT asset_standard_id FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust) X
), 
GroupedActivity AS
(
    SELECT Groups.Code_id,Groups.asset_standard_id,Count = CASE WHEN Activity.Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Activity.Count END
    FROM Groups
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Activity ON Activity.Code_id = Groups.Code_id AND Activity.asset_standard_id = Groups.asset_standard_id
)
SELECT
    C.pkey,
    G.Code_id,
    G.asset_standard_id,
    G.Count,
    C.date_completed
FROM
    @imvw_woap_code_with_cust C
    INNER JOIN GroupedActivity G ON G.Code_id = C.Code_id AND G.asset_standard_id = C.asset_standard_id
WHERE
    G.asset_standard_id = '2 west' and date_completed > '2017-09-10 02:00:30.013' and date_completed < '2017-09-12 02:00:30.013'
```

Which can be shortened to the query below if standards with no activity can be omitted.

```
;WITH Activity As
(
    SELECT Count = COUNT(*),Customer.Code_id,Customer.asset_standard_id
    FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust Customer
    GROUP BY Customer.Code_id,asset_standard_id
)

SELECT
    C.pkey,
    G.Code_id,
    G.asset_standard_id,
    G.Count,
    C.date_completed
FROM
    @imvw_woap_code_with_cust C
    INNER JOIN Activity G ON G.Code_id = C.Code_id AND G.asset_standard_id = C.asset_standard_id
WHERE
    G.asset_standard_id = '2 west' and date_completed > '2017-09-10 02:00:30.013' and date_completed < '2017-09-12 02:00:30.013'
```

Same query using the one you posted above wrapped in a CTE with the date_completed removed. You can overlay the date completed in the final query when the count is aligned with the detail.

```
;WITH GroupedData AS
(
    SELECT
            possibilities.code_id AS code_id,
            possibilities.asset_standard_id,
            Count(U.pkey) AS [COUNT]
    FROM (
        SELECT
            a.asset_standard_id,b.code_id
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT asset_standard_id FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT code_id FROM @imtbl_code
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT CODE_ID AS [ID] FROM @imvw_woap_code_with_cust 
        ) AS b
    ) AS possibilities
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @imvw_woap_code_with_cust AS U ON U.code_id = possibilities.code_id
        AND possibilities.asset_standard_id=u.asset_standard_id
        and u.code_type_id='A-Problem'
    GROUP BY possibilities.code_id, possibilities.asset_standard_id
)

SELECT
    G.code_id,
    G.asset_standard_id,
    G.COUNT
    C.date_completed
FROM
    @imvw_woap_code_with_cust C
    INNER JOIN GroupedData G ON G.Code_id = C.Code_id AND G.asset_standard_id = C.asset_standard_id
ORDER BY count
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you group by the date, and there are multiple unique values for the date, you are going to get multiple rows for each date, with a grouped sum for each unique date. Note you are asking for aggregated summary data for each code, asset id, and *date* now.

You will have to get the min or max for the new date values (a different summary) and NOT group by the date, or if you want and you are sure you're not going to get a large list of dates, you could list them in a comma-delineated list for the possible dates for a row, if you want to do that. Here is a example of a distinct list of dates from other tables using a trick with For Xml. There are other examples of on the web.

```
select
    RepName, DateList
from
    (
        select
            FirstName + ' ' + LastName as RepName, PersonID
        from
            Person
        where
            PersonID in (23164,30637,29985,25643)
    ) as p
    cross apply (
        select stuff ( (
            select
                ', ' + convert(varchar(16), CallDate, 101)
            from    
            (
                select
                    distinct TheDate
                from
                    dbo.Info as c
                    inner join Person as p2 on p2.PersonID = c.PersonID
                where
                    p2.PersonID = p.PersonID
            ) as dat
            order by CallDate
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') as DateList
    ) as dateList
```

Comment: Where did you get PersonID from the question above?

Comment: I didn't, I used an example from data I had access to and then attempted to annonymize the original schema. I guess I was not confident in my syntax to do it from memory without testing it first.